# Detect user when joining chat room

Tags: java, irc, chatbot

so i am using the [PircBot](http://www.jibble.org/pircbot.php) to create an IRC chat bot for twitch strictly with java. I want to add a welcome message when a user connect to my chat which i thought the onJoin() method did but sadly did not. The onJoin() method only responded when the bot itself joined a channel and not when all other users joined. Any help?
Ex: "John has joined the channel." - "Bob has joined the channel"

```
public void onJoin(String channel, String sender, String login, String hostname)
{     
       //check to see if another user joines
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`onJoin()` is an abstract method, meaning you should not use it directly. Just add an implementation in your bot class.

For example, mine is

```
public void onJoin(String channel, String sender, String login, String hostname)
{
      if (sender.equalsIgnoreCase(NICK))
          sendMessage(channel, "Connected to Channel");
}
```

Also you should edit your post to show your code. People can't help much if they can't see what you're doing.

Comment: Thx for response, this wasn't what i was hoping for though and you where right about post

Comment: @JohnMurray When you commented `//check to see if another user joins`, is there code there to actually check? If so, then you need to remove it. The `onJoin()` method already does that, you just have to add functionality.